# What is the meaning of cut's -d and -f options

Tags: pipe

How can this pipeline be explained:

```
cat /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f 9 2>&1 | sort | uniq 2>&1 | wc -l
```

I'm learning Unix by myself and I don't really get it. What does `cut -d : -f 7 2>&1` means here?

Comment: What part don't you understand? Did you read the man pages of cat, cut, sort, uniq and wc? Did you try to execute the command in steps and look how the result changes after you add another command?

Comment: yes I read I understood except for cut thing, I couldn't find what does it mean -d : -f 9.  also it was written cut -d : use delim instead of tab for field delimiter, but I don't get it :(

Answer (score 4):

```
cut -d : -f 9 2>&1
```

That's an individual Unix-style command, in the larger context, part of a pipeline.  You can tell that by the whole command having '|' characters in it.

You read Unix-style command lines from left to right. The actual executable (or alias) will be `cut`. The arguments to `cut` are "-d : -f 9", and the whole command has its stderr output redirected to stdout by "2>&1".

One of the skills you need as a Unix or Linux command line user is how to look up commands and their syntax. So, run `man cut`.  That gives us the "man page", a short manual of how to invoke the command. `cut` receives input on its stdin (as fed by the pipe from `cat` in your overall command). It considers its input as character-separated columns, some number per record, where a record is a line. It "cuts" certain columns of each line, and puts those columns (which are just strings) on its stdout, which feeds into `sort` in your example.

Unix-style commands often (but not always) use '-' characters or '--' strings to mark special parts of the command line. '-d' means use the next character as the column delimiter, which is a ':', colon. The '-f' means cut out column 9 from input lines, and print the string on stdout.

The output redirection phrase `2>&1` has the shell that sets up the whole pipeline sending error messages, conventionally printed on file descriptor 2, to the same place as file descriptor 1 (a.k.a. stdout), the pipe to `sort`.

Overall, the pipeline does a common sort of thing: count the number of unique strings in a file. `cat /etc/passwd` put the contents of the file "/etc/passwd", the well-known Unix/Linux/*BSD file that defines a user ID's characteristics, on its stdout.

The `cut` trims out column 9, which on my system doesn't exist. Let's assume it's the numerical form of "user ID". The string representations of user ID (or whatever) go into `sort`, which has no options. `sort` in this case will reorder its input lines in lexical order, but that really doesn't matter, because we're after dupes or unique user IDs.

`sort` sends its output into `uniq`. `uniq` without any flags just watches each line that comes in on stdin. If that line is lexically the same as the line before, it does nothing, otherwise, it prints the line. Since the input is lexically sorted, that means that `uniq` only prints unique lines.  Any duplicates don't get printed.

`wc` receives the input of `uniq`.  With the "-l" flag, `wc` only prints the count of lines it receives. So: the number of unique values of user ID (or whatever is in column 9 of /etc/passwd).

With only minor mods you could make that pipeline count duplicated user IDs (or whatever). `uniq -c` not only just prints unique lines, it will print a count of how many it got in a row.  You could pipe that into `awk '{if ($2 > 1) {print $0}}` to get only the lines with a count greater than 1, the duplicated lines. `wc -l` would only count duplicated lines.

Comment: ooooh Thank you very much for your detailed explanation ^^

Comment: so cat /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f 9 2>&1 | sort | uniq 2>&1 | wc -l    means that  cut out column 7 of content of passwd file sort it ( buts sort it by what? ) and omit repeated lines , finally count how many lines are there?  Is this correct explanation  :( oh also stderrors of cut is outputed in sort , and uniq in wc -l?

Comment: @kyrie - I just elaborated on the entire pipeline's meaning.